# Riesz Representation Theorem in Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I know Riesz Representation Theorem in Hilbert spaces.

If $T$ is a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$ then there exists some $g \in H$ such that for every $f \in H$ we have
$$T(f) =\langle f,g\rangle.$$
Moreover, $\|T\| = \|g\|$ (here $\|T\|$ denotes the operator norm of $T$, while $\|g\|$ is the Hilbert space norm of $g$).

I need couple of examples on different Hilbert spaces.
We know $g$ exists and it is unique. I am looking for example and finding $g$, for example, if we consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ as our space.

Also I am wondering if I can find all bounded linear operators using Riesz Representation Theorem. **To be more specific, if I consider a $g$ using the dot product, I can generate a bounded operator.**

Comment: By "Ritz Rep", I'm guessing you're referring to the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem)?

Comment: Yes You are right

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to exactly what you want. You seem to want an example of the Riesz Representation Theorem, but it's not really something one can verify with examples. I could give you a bunch of examples of bounded linear functionals, and observe that they're all of the given form, but I don't think that's really convincing. I could give you an alternate proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem specific to the space $\Bbb{R}^2$, if that would help?

Comment: What I am looking for is a bounded functional and show thqat it can be uniquely written as a dot product thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then you have the standard basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$. Then given a linear functional $T$,
\begin{align*}
T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) &= T(x_1 e_1 + x_2 e_2 + \ldots + x_n e_n) \\
&= x_1 T(e_1) + x_2 T(e_2) + \ldots + x_n T(e_n) \\
&= (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot (T(e_1), \ldots, T(e_n)).
\end{align*}
Thus, we have a vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$ which represents $T$. Is it the only one? Let's suppose that $(u_1, \ldots, u_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n$ also represents $T$. That is, for all $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \Bbb{R}^n$,
$$T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot (u_1, \ldots, u_n).$$
Plugging in $e_i$, we get,
$$T(e_i) = 0u_1 + 0u_2 + \ldots + 0u_{i-1} + 1 u_i + 0u_{i+1} + \ldots + 0u_n = u_i.$$
Therefore $u_i = T(e_i)$ for all $i$, and so
$$(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = (T(e_1), \ldots, T(e_n)),$$
i.e. the representative is unique.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to give another example(on l^2 or any othe space.)

Comment: @Keon I don't know of any alternative proofs in any infinite-dimensional spaces, sorry. Things inevitably get trickier in infinite-dimensional spaces, since you also need to factor in completeness; the Riesz Representation Theorem does not hold in incomplete inner product spaces.

Comment: thank you very much. best wishes

Comment: I know the proof of Ritz rep theorem. I need some examples to see how g can ee found. like the one you provided